# Learn windows 10 apps

Tags: windows-10

What is a good place to learn how to write applications for Windows 10?

I prefer online and I prefer free.

I have tried Google but was not happy with the results.

Comment: Then you aren't googling the right things. First of all try deciding **what type** of app you want to write, wpf, console, web, winforms, etc.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to StackOverflow! It is generally advisable to ask questions with a specific answer, mostly about programming and related fields thereof. I would recommend reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent course at Microsoft Virtual Academy covering Windows 10 development at https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/a-developer-s-guide-to-windows-10-12618